how to prevent infringement via additional elements to the precedent of a conditional step in your claim
let's suppose that the claim is for the "swipe":
 1. a first user swipes right on a second user
 2. said second user swipe right on said first user

If:

 1. said first user's swipe and said second's swipe are verified

then:

unlock communications

Infringer A:
 1. a first user swipes right on a second user
 2. said second user swipe right on said first user

If:

 1. said first user's swipe and said second's swipe are verified
 2. said first user and said second user is within 5 years of age

then:

unlock communications


The competitor has successfully bypassed literal infringement.
But the crux of the idea and invention is the swipe.
How can the first claim be changed to prevent all possible infringements via additional conditions to the precedent of the claim as in Infringer A?

Have you considered something along the lines of "unlocking communications based at least partly on whether said first user's swipe and said second's swipe are verified"?
For more examples: https://patents.google.com/?q=CL%3d(based+at+least+partly+on)
Not sure what it means to "verify" a swipe, however, but that is not really relevant here.

actually, that's what I tried to ask in this question https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/25883/a-claim-where-the-precedent-of-a-conditional-step-can-have-multiple-possible-oth
